# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

When is use the following code without mysql_real_escape_string, works fine. I simply trying to grab a text string that may have apost. from an input form and format it to put in mysql table.

```
    <?php
    $filenamee = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filename =strval($filenamee);
    echo "file name is".$filename;

     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","blasbott_admin","lubu1973","blasbott_upload");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 $companyName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['companyName']);
// $companyName = mysql_real_escape_string($companyNamee);
 //$companyName = mysql_real_escape_string($companyNamee);

$sql="INSERT INTO ads (companyName, webSite, picture)
 VALUES ('$companyName','$_POST[webSite]','$filename')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
   echo"<br>";
 echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Are those your actual database connection details?

Comment: Instead of escaping the $_POST data have you thought about using prepared statements ? You are trying to escape the companyName but then you are directly Posting['website'] into your query.

Comment: no actual values; just fooling local until i build somthing actual.  I'll have a look at prepared statments. I don't know much, but someone warned me about mysql injections.  Thanks for your help; love the people here.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i did read a few posts on this first.  It was a novice mistake mixing mysqli_real_escape_string  with mysql_real_escape_string  However im glad i made it and learned about mysql injections, and south coast web lead me to prepared statments thx south

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're at risk of MySQL injections. Never insert data directly to a database without some sort of projection first. It's a major security risk. Also use mysqli_real_escape_string instead, and note that your $_POST[webSite] is unprotected.

Also, your error means that your database details are not correct.

Comment: changing to mysqli_real_escape_string  solved things. Reading up on mysql injections to protect the database. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for bringing those security risks to my attention.  mysqli_real_escape_string solved the problem, but i didn't know about mysql injections; thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` was the fix for me.  Didn't realize I had to use that when I was using mysqli.  Makes sense though since it uses the connection you opened.

Answer (score 9):

No, you shouldn't mix mysql and mysqli.

Use here instead of `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`:

```
$con->real_escape_string($var);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must connect with database first before using Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 2):

A working code example that is a solution to this problem is available here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: Why did you answer this old question?

Comment: I had the problem and came across this thread so decided to leave it here for people who come here after me while googling the same thing. Age is more or less irrelevant for some questions and the answers here did not solve the problem in a way that was understandable for me. The example I linked to is a lot more obvious and explicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead.