# mysql_real_escape_string() access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password no)errors shown in uploading php scrip

Tags: php

my code is given below

it works fine in my computer but when uploading it to server it shows error like

mysql_real_escape_string() access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password no)errors shown in uploading php scrip

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['upload'])&&$_FILES['userfile']['size']>0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];


$yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
$author  = $_POST['author'];
$sem = $_POST['sem'];
$branch = $_POST['branch'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];


$fileType=(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==0 ? mysql_real_escape_string(
$_FILES['userfile']['type']) : mysql_real_escape_string(
stripslashes ($_FILES['userfile'])));
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','XXX', 'XXX') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('test@engineeringnote.tk', $con);
if($db){
$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content,yourname,author,sem,branch,subject ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content','$yourname','$author','$sem','$branch','$subject')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
mysql_close();
echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded .will be published in 24 hours<br>";
}else { echo "file upload failed"; }
} 
?
```

Comment: check your mysql username and password for server

Comment: Read the note here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php.

Comment: Your password is in your code.

Comment: mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

Comment: That is not related to `mysql_real_escape_string`. Your username and/or password is incorrect. B.t.w. You don't even call `mysql_real_escape_string()` in this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_real\_escape\_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870024/warning-mysql-real-escape-string-access-denied-for-user-localhost-usin)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct "HOST NAME", its usually the IP Address for your phpmyadmin,
make sure you are using the correct user too, "USERNAME AND PASSWORD".

Finally!!, Don't use MySQL, try MySQLi or PDO instead,

P.S Edit user POST and remove your passwords :).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `mysql_real_escape_string()` without a link established to **mysql**.
You have used the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function before connecting to the **mysql**.

Please move the following lines on the top of the page:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','XXX', 'XXX') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('test@engineeringnote.tk', $con);
```

or just move it above the `mysql_real_escape_string()` and make sure the DB connection credentials are right.

Although the usage of `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not write

Please refer: **http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string**