# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in easy-contact-forms-database.php on line 152

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form

I am using a wordpress plugin name Easy Contact Forms. The issue is that it is showing warnings and due to that i am unable to login my admin panel. The warnings are :

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /public_html/new/wp-content/plugins/easy-contact-forms/easy-contact-forms-database.php on line 152


Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /public_html/new/wp-content/plugins/easy-contact-forms/easy-contact-forms-database.php on line 152
```

I searched regarding the issue but not found any solution.

I hope you guys will give me a solution to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: check this link it may helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870024/warning-mysql-real-escape-string-access-denied-for-user-localhost-usin

Comment: check the credentials provided for database connection.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue. I could not really identify the problem, but I was able to narrow-it down to my current theme and Easy Contact Form Plugin.
This is what I did, and it helped me:

A) Access your server using FTP. Find the directory where your wordpress is installed. If you use a shared hosting, most probably it is in public_html/yoursite folder

B) Go to wp-content/themes folder. Rename your current active theme to something else such as "theme-backup-date".

C) Go to wp-content/plugins/ folder and rename Easy contact Form Plugin to something else as well..

D) go to yoursite/wp-admin/themes.php
This will revert the site to default theme and omit theme-related errors at least.

E) Now you shall be able to log-in to your wordpress admin panel. Log-in, then delete the unavailable plugin (the one you just renamed).

F) go back to theme folder mentioned above (using your ftp client again) and rename it back to what it was before.

C) Re-install Contact Forms plugin if you still need it.